# Do the parallel-for in .net 4.0 takes privilege of GPU computing automatically?

Tags: .net-4.0, gpgpu, parallel.for

Do the parallel-for in .net 4.0 takes privilege of GPU computing automatically? Or I have to configure with some drivers so that it uses GPU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, PFX doesn't do that for you. Take a look at [Microsoft Accelerator](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/Accelerator/) to run some code on a GPU. I recommend in particular [Tomas Petricek's series of articles on F# and Accelerator](http://tomasp.net/blog/accelerator-intro.aspx).

Also watch the [gpu branch of LinqOptimizer](https://github.com/nessos/LinqOptimizer/tree/gpu).

Comment: 2/3 of your links are also broken.

Comment: @bostIT that's why answers are editable by anyone in SO. Answer is five years old.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take advantage of GPU parallelism for .NET, try the open soure [Brahma](http://sourceforge.net/projects/brahma-fx/) library, noting that in its current incarnation is .NET 3.5.  It's LINQ-able, just not 4.0 parallel LINQ-able.

Comment: I updated the link to go to the SourceForge host page.  The project appears to be pretty dormant, though.

Answer (score 0):

`Parallel.For` does not use the GPU in your graphics card.  It uses threads, multiple cores and hyperthreading to achieve its goals.  There are no drivers available that will allow Parallel.For to make use of the GPU.

The only technology that I know of that allows you to parallelize work in the GPU (other than graphical processing work) is [CUDA](http://www.nvidia.com/object/what_is_cuda_new.html).